# Configuration file for managed Http Module

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7

I have a custom HttpModule installed on IIS 7 and is working just fine. Now I want to put settings in a configuration file where I can change them without rebuilding a new module each time.

Where should I put these settings as this module is not hosted inside any application and is server-level module. (being executed before any application).

cheers

Comment: One of possible solutions can be placing a separate config file somewhere shared (c:\sharedconfigs) and then read the config file form that hardcoded location.

But I want something more standard. the web config file which is used when accessing the `ConfigurationManager` class is web.config file of current application which the request will be handled to. Maybe I can access the applicationhost.config by using `ConfigurationManager` !?

Comment: It seems that for simple `appSettings` values you can use IIS Manager UI and add values to configuration file of root node. then you can access you values just as normal settings using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`. I still have no idea about custom sections in configuration files. And this configuration file, on my x64 computer with .NET 2, is located in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK,

Here is the result of googling and more research on this issue:

1. There is another question [about adding custom section in iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750213/edit-config-custom-section-in-iis)
2. Which itself links to [another article](http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/extending-iis-configuration/extending-iis-schema-and-accessing-the-custom-sections-using-mwa)

So, it seems that it is possible to do such thing as storing shared configuration among sites (to be consumed by IIS7 server level module) in custom configuration section.